# ActiveRecord query an associated entity

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord, orm

I have had a hard time searching for the answer to this. I think it boils down to me not knowing exactly what to search for.

Say I have a two tables, `Customers` and `Orders` where a customer may have many orders. To get all of a customers order I could just run `Customer.find(1).orders`. However what if I want to filter the returned array to those orders between a certain date range? What is the most efficient way to do that using ActiveRecord? I could alternatively use the `select` method on the array to filter it, but what if a customer has 10000+ orders. This could be horribly inefficient.

I read that perhaps named scopes could help me with this. Is this a sensible approach

Any wisdom or experience with ActiveRecord would be most appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to see if there's anything in there you can use? "Scopes" in the context of Active Record queries are really just pre-packaged query method chains. You can use a scope, but you still need to understand how to use the underlying query methods to make one. You could also use the same methods without packaging them into a scope. A scope is just a handy shortcut/alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write this in AREL and based on your DB server the query may vary, but here is a very simplistic date range scope:

```
class Orders < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :some_date_range, -> { where("#{table_name}.date_from BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to", date_from: Date.today, date_to: Date.today + 1.day) }
end

Customer.find(1).orders.some_date_range
```

Comment: So does calling Customer.find(1).orders return an ActiveRecord::Relation object and not an array? my concern was that a very large array could be returned before then being filtered. Is this not the case?

Comment: `scope` will always return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You can read about it [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/)